# Split XML and binary data - invalid indatastring

Tags: c#, xml, base64, bin

I need to split the xml part from the binary part, but I am getting an invalid 64-basestring. Any ideas how to proceed?

```
byte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string[] binPartArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(allData).Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/").Split(new string[] { "</EndTableHeader>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
byte[] binData = Convert.FromBase64String(binPartArray[1])
```

Comment: Provide sample of input file.

Comment: </EndTableHeader>   
 IT Department -> There is a rectangle symbol after the > sign, which I cant copy in here.

Comment: I would recommend for reading XML, for example

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("EndTableHeader");

and then I would do the string operation and transfer from base64

Comment: Do you know what the hex value of the rectangle symbol?

Comment: William: The binary data is separated from the XML. The file consists of header (XML) followed by the binary part.

Comment: is the xml telling you anything about the content and it's encoding? Are you sure, that the binary part is `base64`? Is the binary part **outside** of the XML entirely?

Comment: Yes. The XML is in the header and then its separated by a rectangle sign (perhaps 7F HEX). The xml header looks like this; <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: I would think the end is an EOH (0x02) but code be wrong.  You con find offset using int offset = Array.BinarySearch(allData, 0x03);  Then copy binary to new array : allData.CopyTo(newArray, offset + 1);

Comment: The end is Hex 00.

Comment: Phero, normally you'd be told not to paste pictures, but in this case it might help, to place a screenshot of your file (how you see it). Try to open it with a hex editor (eg. "tiny hexer"). The xml-declaration you provide in your comment is not an XML but just a declaration. Is there nothing more human readable?

Comment: If just put the file in bytes, like this it: byte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), but it reads from the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, if you do not provide more details, you won't get any help...

Comment: Sorry .. I added this line and it worked: byte[] binData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(binPartArray[1]));